# Are not list-questions off-topic in this site?

Tags: support, on-topic, closed-questions, off-topic

Are not list-questions off-topic in this site? If so, why?

Comment: Is there a particular question you're wondering about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List questions are usually avoided on Stack Exchange (see e.g. this answer on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/340816)). However, non-list questions would include *every* other type of question, and it is not possible to make general statements about every type of question that is not a list question.

Please check the questions tagged [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic), [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), and if those questions do not cover what you need to know, ask a more specific question.

Comment: You should use "meta-tag:" instead of "tag:" for tags on meta: [meta-tag:on-topic], [meta-tag:off-topic]. By the way, questions tagged with [meta-tag:scope] might also be relevant for looking for these discussions.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks, I have updated my answer.